# Facing Problem with firebase while registering user

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an app which inserts data of shop from the user into SQLite database. Data consists of shopname, shopLocation and shopContact. I am trying to get that data on the firebase database. For that, with the help of cursor Data is being retrieved and pass to FirebaseDatabase. But this task is getting failed
Following is the code
No email is required while using the app and so the password that's why email and password is generated within the app.

```
public void RegisterUser(View view)
    {
        Cursor shopData = demoSQLite.getData();

        if(shopData.getCount() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            while(shopData.moveToNext())
            {
                shopNameData = shopData.getString(0);
                shopLocationData = shopData.getString(1);
                shopContactData = shopData.getString(2);
            }
        }

        String shopEmail = shopNameData + "_" + shopLocationData + "@gmail.com";
        String passwordData = "password@123";

        Log.i("User", shopEmail + passwordData);

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(shopEmail, passwordData)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            User user = new User(shopNameData, shopLocationData, shopContactData);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener
                                    (new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                            {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                {
                                                    Log.i("User Data", "Data is uploaded");
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    Log.i("User Data", "Data is not uploaded");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                        }

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.i("Task", "Failed"); // While task is failed this message is displayed.
                    }
                });

    }
```

error is

```
I/Task: Failed 
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@d9d02e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the internet permissions in your manifest file?

If not then add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope this helps :)